# Why does this code have an IndentationError?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, double

I am trying to write a program where the user enters a Int value then the int has to be compared using If statement and the result has to be printered and If the user enters a string then the message should be  "you have entered a string value".

Can you let me know what is wrong with my program

```
print ("Enter a value")
input()
if int (value) == 10:
print('The value is 10')
if (value) == str:       (Its wrong in here)
print (' Enter a Number not text')
elif int (value) == 12:
print('The value is not 10')
else: 
print('The value is not a number')
```

```
Error message        File "<ipython-input-35-29c9dd2647d4>", line 6
     print (' Enter a Number not text') IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Do you know how important indentation is in Python? Have you looked up how indentation works?

Comment: Thats what you get when you copy paste code from some word file or pdf etc.

Comment: When i try to bols my post in stackoverflow i was not able to post in the way which i had so i posted as it was

Comment: print (' Enter a number : ')
input()
if int(w) == 10:
    print('The value is 10')
elif int(w) == 20:
    print('The value is 20')
else: 
    print('The value is  30')

Comment: @LokeshGovindaraju it's useless to post code in comments, since it gets rid of formatting and whitespace. Whitespace/indentation is critical in Python anyway like I said.

Answer (score -1):

```
print("Enter a value")
value = input()
if not value.isnumeric():
    print("Enter a Number not text")
elif int (value) == 10:
    print("The value is 10") 
elif int (value) == 12: 
    print("The value is not 10")
```